# Printing X amount of Items in a Row in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, loops, printing, row

I want to print 4 items in a row, I'm using the code below, it works except there's a flaw and I don't know how to fix.

```
for (i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items.length-1 == i) {
    document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += "<div style='display: inline-block;'>" + items[i] + "</div>"
  } else {
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
      document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += "<div style='display: inline-block;'>" + items[i] + "</div>, <br>"
     } else {
      document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += "<div style='display: inline-block;'>" + items[i] + "</div>, "  
     }
```

It always prints like this:

```
#,
#,#,#,#,
#,#,#,#,
#,#,#
```

Which I want it to print like:

```
#,#,#,#,
#,#,#,#,
#,#,#,#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this.

CSS

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='items'></div>
```

Javascript

```
var itemsEl = document.getElementById("items"),
    items = ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
    itemsLen = items.length,
    itemLast = itemsLen - 1,
    iter,
    itemDiv,
    groupDiv;

for (iter = 0; iter < itemsLen; iter += 1) {
    itemDiv = document.createElement('div');
    itemDiv.className = 'item';
    itemDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[iter]));

    if (iter % 4 === 0) {
        groupDiv = itemsEl.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        groupDiv.className = 'group'
    }

    if (iter !== itemLast) {
        itemDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(','));
    }

    groupDiv.appendChild(itemDiv);
}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/476psLoz/)

Additional

Depending on the number of items, you could improve this by using a [`documentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) to which you can append your groups and items to, and then only when this is complete then append the fragment to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this looks so complex to me, the answer below, i%4 == 3, is way simple and works. Also maybe there is some performance difference compared to yours which I think would be slow?

Comment: I don't know what you find complex about it? This solution is most likely to be as performant and probably has better performance than your original example or any modification of that. I'm not going to say `is` because I haven't compared their performances. For me, this is far more readable and maintainable code. If there is something you don't understand then I am willing to give you further explanation and reading.

Comment: I'm going to choose this as an answer, just because indeed its more maintainable and teaching some other little details.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
if (i % 4 == 0)
```

You need: (i+1) % 4 == 0 ... the array index starts from 0, so the 4-th element has index 3.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (i % 4 == 0) {
  document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += "<div style='display: inline-block;'>" + items[i] + "</div>, <br>"
```

to

```
 if (i % 4 == 0 && i!= 0) {
  document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += "<br><div style='display: inline-block;'>" + items[i] + "</div>,";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yefxjx0r/

And cleaner solution would be:
http://jsfiddle.net/d7me3dff/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works and thanks for the cleaner solution as well, but in that one there's a little flaw, it adds comma at the end, which I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The condition using which you are checking whether forth '#' is to be printed is wrong. It should be 
`if ((i+1) % 4 == 0)`

```
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items.length - 1 == i) {
        document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += "<div style='display: inline-block;'>" + items[i] + "</div>"
    } else {
        if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
            document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += "<div style='display: inline-block;'>" + items[i] + "</div>, <br>"
        } else {
            document.getElementById("items").innerHTML += "<div style='display: inline-block;'>" + items[i] + "</div>, "
        }
    }
}
```

Check this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ktyLkypp/

Answer (score 1):

Just change `if (i % 4 == 0)` to `if (i % 4 == 3)`

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining the structure of your code, because the array's index starts at 0 but you need to check the index % 4, you can just rewrite the for conditions in this way: `for (i=1; i <= items.length; i++) {` and access the items with `items[i-1]` .

Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lv08gq6/).